# How to make international phone calls from my computer' through my SIP server?

Tags: networking, voip, sip

I'm currently working for a scientific company, and I'm the only programmer here, and the company wants me to use one of their servers to setup a SIP server, and somehow be able to make calls to landlines in other countries.

Also the company wants the computer to be able to make multiple calls at a time.

I have successfully installed a SIP:Wise distribution on their server, and have successfully connected to it using Jitsi, I can add friends inside of Jitsi and call them, problem is it only works on the two computer that are connected to each other, people from outside the network can't connect to the server, but I'm pretty sure that it is a port forwarding problem so no big issue there.

The issue is when I try to make a call to any number with Jitsi it tells me "PSTN Termination Currently Unavailable", this is where I don't know where I am going wrong, I'm thinking that maybe this software is too old and I need a newer software? Or is it a config problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect the **SIP:Wise** to a VoIP/SIP Telecom provider, who will be your link to the *PSTN* (Landlines) world.

Check with the main service providers in your country if they provide the service. However, there are international providers that give very good long distance rates.

I use *www.cheapvoip.com*, but there are a lot of providers. Check [this](http://www.voipratetracker.com/compare_rates) to find the one most useful for you. Keep in mind that the provider must give SIP service to be compatible with your server.